# Multipart request does not work

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is what I currently have, put together by different blogs trying to describe how to do a multipart request in Angular. However, it does not work. It says Bad request (400). What is wrong? Is it because it miss the content-type beneath the Content-Disposition header? How do I add that if that is the case?

```
        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append('data', server);

        return $http.post('/servers', fd, {
            transformRequest: angular.identity,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': undefined
            }
        });
```

Request payload from Chrome

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryoWOUGkw6GayCLwSB
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="data"

{"status":"REJECTED","description":"Test"}
------WebKitFormBoundaryoWOUGkw6GayCLwSB--
```

Comment: Why do you set the content-type to be undefined? can you set it to `multipart/mixed` or `multipart/form-data`?

Comment: @sza I think that's the answer mate, put it below :)

Comment: No, it does not work!